# Cómo añadir espacios cuando un número está seguido de una letra

Tags: php, string

tengo este texto en UTF-8

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-
```

como se puede observar, en `根３丁` no hay espacios, quisiera que termine siendo `根 ３ 丁` por ejemplo, lo mismo con `-２V` y añadir espacios quedando `- ２ V`

como resultado final estoy buscando que el texto sea

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根 ３ 丁目 １３- ２ V-
```

es decir, añadiendo espacios mientras no hayan números al lado (por ejemplo ese `１３-`, **debe seguir igual**)

lo que tengo actualmente elimina todos los números y les añade un espacio

```
$string = preg_replace('/\d+/u', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: mmm... jolin, ahora me doy cuenta de otro problema que vas a tener con eso... pues que no son números que puedas interpretar con un preg_replace como tales, ¡sino que son caracteres unicode que parecen números!  Es decir, vas a tener que buscarlos como tales (aquí un ejemplo de [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140734/unicode-preg-replace-problem-in-php) para ello).  Ya me parecia a mi que esos números eran un poco grandes en mi pantalla... porque son de este tipo: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280&number=128  (mírate los FULLWIDTH DIGIT)

Comment: Quizás primero deberias convertirlos a "normales" y luego realizar la separación, o bien directamente pero sabiendo que los tendras que buscar con su código unicode o hex.  Esto del japones se lia bastante veo, je. Suerte!  (lo he descubierto al intentar usar https://regex101.com/ para encontrar la expresion regular que necesitas y ver que no me cogia ni un numero)

Comment: así es, tengo ese problema justamente porque son japoneses, está bastante complicado porque no son realmente números

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según parece, los caracteres **UTF8** responden bastante bien a las [sintaxis de expresiones regulares de PCRE](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) usadas por [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php).

Por lo tanto, podemos aprovecharnos de eso gracias a que la secuencia de escape [`\d`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php) reconoce como dígitos también los [*FULLWIDTH DIGIT*](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280&number=128) de unicode que aparecen en tu pregunta. Y por otro lado, la [clase carácter](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) `alpha` también interpreta correctamente los caracteres japoneses, sin mezclarlos con signos de puntuación como guiones y demás.

Por lo tanto, basándonos en eso, he establecido dos ejecuciones de `preg_replace` seguidas para conseguir el propósito de la pregunta.

Estas son las siguientes:

```php
// utf8 con caracteres FULLWIDTH DIGIT en unicode
$string = "名古屋市北区,大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-";  

// primer caso, cuando un caracter alfanumérico precede a un dígito
$string = preg_replace('/([[:alpha:]])(\d+)/u', '${1} ${2}', $string);

// segundo caso, cuando un dígito precede a un caracter alfanumérico
$string = preg_replace('/(\d+)([[:alpha:]])/u', '${1} ${2}', $string);

// mostramos la salida
echo $string;
```

Es decir, veniamos de aquí:

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-
```

y nos termina mostrando esto:

```
名古屋市北区,大曽根 ３ 丁目 １３-２ V-
```

Seguramente hay alguna forma de ponerlas todas en una expresión regular, pero no la he sabido hallar de momento.